# Unable to switch to iFrame using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriver

I'm currently trying out Selenium for Python to do some web automation.
I got stuck a the checkout where you have to enter your credit card data.
I'm aware that I have to switch to iFrame to locate the input box.
But I was never able to switch the frame.
I tried it for ID or for example for this:

```
time.sleep(4)
frame = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name= '__privateHeidelpayFrame--heidelpay-holder-iframe-1616489954834']")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
name_input = self.driver.find_element_by_id("card-holder")
name_input.clear()
name_input.send_keys(credit_card.NAME)
```

I'm always getting "Unable to locate element : `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@name= '__privateHeidelpayFrame--heidelpay-holder-iframe-1616489954834']"}".`

I added a pic from the Source Code.
[Source Code from the Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQccV.png)

I'm thankful for any advise!
Best, Jannic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly id & name attribute is dynamic.

Try with `starts-with()` or use other attribute like class to identify the iframe.

```
frame = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, '__privateHeidelpayFrame--heidelpay-holder-iframe-')]")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

OR

```
frame = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='heidelpayUIIframe']")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Comment: Oh great! Both ways are working. So I use ''starts-with()'' if attributes change dynamically. I also tried the class option before, but probably messed that up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a simpler API to find the iFrame?

Does

```py
self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "__privateHeidelpayFrame--heidelpay-holder-iframe-1616489954834'")
```

Return anything?

Comment: Atm I'm not familiar with a different API other than Selenium. I tried your solution, but it returns still the same error, that the element is not able to be located.